# Proving that the set of limit points of a set is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

From Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (Chapter 2, Exercise 6)

Let $E'$ be the set of all limit points of a set $E$. Prove that $E'$ is closed.

I think I got it but my argument is a bit hand wavy:

If $x$ is a limit point of $E'$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains some $y\in E'$, and every neighborhood of $y$ contains some $z\in E$. Therefore every neighborhood of $x$ contains some $z\in E$, and so $x$ is a limit point of $E$. Then $x\in E'$, so $E'$ is closed.

The thing that's bugging me is the leap from one neighborhood to another. Is this formally correct?

Comment: You can see an answer [here](http://binarybeta.blogspot.com/2014/06/set-of-all-limit-points-of-set-is-closed.html).

Comment: If your space is Hausdorff the leap is easy

Comment: How do you know $x \neq z$? Perhaps $x \neq y$ and $y \neq z$ but $x = z$.

Comment: Here's a sketch of a proof. -- The set of limit points of $E$ is just the closure of $E$ minus the isolated points of $E$. By definition, any isolated point has an open neighbourhood not intersecting the rest of $E$; the complement of this neighbourhood is closed. So the set of limit points is the intersection of the closure of $E$ and a bunch of other closed sets (corresponding to isolated points), hence is closed itself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your argument is correct, but incomplete: All you need to finish it is to ensure that you can find a neighborhood of $y$ contained in the neighborhood of $x$ that you began with (any will do, since all contain elements of $E$). Use the triangle inequality to find an appropriate radius for the neighborhood of $y$.

Comment: Let's see if I got this straight: Let $r'=d(x,y)<r$, for some $y$ in $x$'s neighborhood of radius $r$. Then consider the neighborhood of $y$ with radius $r-r'$. This one is contained in $x$'s neighborhood and contains some $z\in E$. Is this correct? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FernandoMartin the neighborhood of $y$ with radius $r - r'$ contains $x$'s neighborhood, not the other way around.

Comment: @DonLarynx: I'm pretty sure it is correct.

Comment: Just a question: I managed to find a proof that the set a limitpoints of a set is closed, but this under the extra condition that singletons are closed. Is the statement true in general? The answers on this page are all dealing with metric spaces.

Comment: Never mind. I have found http://math.stackexchange.com/q/490968/75923

Comment: Why do we need the triangle inequality? I think its enough to choose $r<d(x,y)$ because we want the neighborhood of y to be a subset of neighborhood of x. ($N_r(y)\subset N_R(x)$

Comment: Both the original post and the accepted answer miss a subtle detail: That in the process of finding z, nothing is stopping this z from being x again. Therefore, one cannot say that every nbhd of x intersects E at a point other than x. That is, one cannot say $x \in E'$ Why is this subtlety missed? Well the fact of the statement is only true for $T_1$ spaces, and therefore, must use a property equivalent to $T_1$ in its proof.

Comment: No subtlety missed, but thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 19):

Let $\hat S$ be the set of all limit points of $S$. Prove that $\hat S$ is a closed set.

**Proof**: Suppose $x_0$ is a limit point of $\hat S$. Then given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $x \in \hat S$ with $\vert x - x_0\vert < \frac\varepsilon2$. Now $x \in \hat S$ is a limit point of $S$ so there exists $x' \in S$ such that $\vert x' - x \vert < \frac\varepsilon2$. Now $$\vert x' - x_0 \vert = \vert x' - x + x - x_0 \vert \leq \vert x' - x \vert + \vert x - x_0 \vert < \frac\varepsilon2 + \frac\varepsilon2 = \varepsilon$$ Thus $x_0$ is a limit point of $S$ and by definition is contained in $\hat S$. We have shown that $\hat S$ contains all of its limit points. By theorem that states that a set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points, we have just shown that $\hat S$ is a closed set.

Comment: You should use the metric form $\mathrm{d}$ and not $|\cdot|$.

Comment: Any specific reason @StevenGamer? I like this form.

Comment: It is more general; you may have metric spaces that do not have addition or subtraction defined.  However, if take merely as a notational convenience, then that is fair enough.

Comment: I think that there is something missing in your proof. In the definition of a limit point you need $x' \neq x_0$ and your proof doesn't ensure that.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure that they are not equal?

Comment: We have that |x′−x| is strictly less than min(ε/2, |x−$x_0$|). This will ensure that x′ ≠ $x_0$.

Answer (score 8):

Let $x$ be a limit point of $E'$, and let $\varepsilon >0$. Then (by definition) there exists $y\in E'$ such that $0<d(x,y)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Since $y\in E'$ there exists $z\in E$ such that $0<d(y,z)<d(x,y)$ (here one uses $d(x,y)$ as the epsilon from the definition of a limit point).

By triangle inequality we have $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)<\varepsilon$, and note that indeed $x\neq y$. So (by definition) $x$ is a limit point of $E$. That is $E'' \subseteq E'$, which proves that $E'$ is closed.

Answer (score 3):

If x is a limit point of E', then
$$\forall x \forall r > 0 ( d(x, y) < r \to \exists y \in E' )$$
There exists a positive real number h such that $d(x, y) = r - h$.

y is a limit point of E, then
$$\forall y ( d(y, z) < h \to \exists z \in E )$$

So, 
$$\forall x \forall r > 0 ( d(x, z) < d(x, y) + d(y, z) = r \to \exists z \in E )$$
Thus x is a limit point of E, $x \in E'$.

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent definition of a neighborhood of $x$ is that it is an open set containing $x$. If you adopt this definition, then your proof is perfect.

Comment: did you mean, "a set that contains an open set containing $x$"? If not, what is the definition of nbd that you take to begin with?

Comment: @Arturo. Edited my answer. I meant some authors define "neighborhood" this way.

Comment: What do you mean by “equivalent” here?

Answer (score 2):

I thought the following, could someone validate if I'm not mistaken or mixed up? ;)

Proving that $A'$ is closed is equivalent to prove that $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus A'$ is open

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus A'\iff\exists B_{r}\left(x\right):B\cap A\setminus\left\{ x\right\} =\emptyset$ for some $r>0$

Let $B*:=B\setminus\left\{ x\right\} $ and take any $y\in B*\Longrightarrow B*\cap A\setminus\left\{ y\right\} =\emptyset\Longrightarrow y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus A'\Longrightarrow B\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus A'\Longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus A'=\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus A'\right)^{o}\Longrightarrow A'=\overline{A'}$ So $A'$ is closed

Answer (score 1):

You want to use that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains an open neighbourhood of $x$. Now an open set is, by definition, a neighbourhood of each of its elements.

In the case of a metric space, $\varepsilon$-neighbourhoods can be used, and depending on your definitions and what has already been proved, you may need to use the triangle inequality to show that they are open.

Answer (score 1):

Let x is limit point of E'.So $\forall\epsilon>0\exists y\in E'$ such that |x-y|<$\epsilon$/2 
Now as E' contatain all limit points of E therefore $\forall y\in E'\forall \epsilon>0\exists z\in E$ such that |y-z|<$\epsilon$/2 
Now consider |x-z|$\le$|x-y|+|y-z|$\le$ $\epsilon$By Triangular Inequality. 
x $\in E'$.This is true for every limit point of E'.
 This implies Set of limit point is closed set

Answer (score 1):

It is actually enough to assume that your space is $T_1$. If this is the case, then $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ iff every open set $V$ around $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$. Let $x\in\overline{A'}$, and take $V\in\mathscr{O}_x$. Then there is $y\in V\cap A'$, which means that $V\cap A$ is infinite, and so $x\in A'$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space and $A \subseteq X$. Notice that $A'$ is closed $\iff \overline{A'} = A' \iff A'' \subseteq A' $ since $\overline{A'} = A' \cup A'' $. Hence, we show that $A''\subseteq A'$.

Let $x \in A''$. Thus, for every open nbhd $U_x$ of $x$, one has $U_x \cap (A' \setminus \{x\}) \neq \emptyset $.

Pick $y \in U_x \cap (A' \setminus \{x\})$. As $y \in U_x$ and $U_x$ is an open set, there exists an open nbhd $V_y$ of $y$ entirely contained in $U_x$. Moreover, as $X$ is $T_1$, singletons are closed, so $\{x\}$ is a closed subset of $X$. Therefore, $V_y \setminus \{x\} = V_y \cap \{x\}^C$ is the intersection of open subsets of $X$ and so, is also open in $X$, contains $y$, and is entirely contained in $U_x$. **(This is the subtlety missed by OP and accepted answer)**

Now, as $y \in A'$, then for every open nbhd $U_y$ of $y$, one has $U_y \cap (A \setminus \{y\}) \neq \emptyset $. In particular, this property also applies to the nbhd $V_y \setminus \{x\} $ of $y$.

Picking now $z \in (V_y \setminus \{x\} ) \cap (A \setminus \{y\}) $, we have that $z \in V_y \setminus \{x\} \subset U_x$, where $z \neq x$. Therefore, for every open nbhd $U_x$ of $x$, one has $U_x \cap (A \setminus \{x\}) \neq \emptyset$.

Hence, $x \in A'$.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above I found good but I also found there was a step that needed further justification (I elaborate after proof for context reasons), I also write this in the spirit of *"Understanding analysis"* by Stephen Abbott for there is a similar exercise in the book, the notation is kept similar for those who like me tried searching for answers. This proof is similar to the one found in the instructor manual for the aforementioned book.

Notation used below

- Epsilon neighbourhood

> $V_\epsilon(a):= \{x\in\mathbb{R}: \lvert x-a\rvert<\epsilon\} = (a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$

- Punctured epsilon neighbourhood

> $V_\epsilon(a)\setminus\{x\}:= \{x\in\mathbb{R}: 0<\lvert x-a\rvert<\epsilon\} = (a-\epsilon,a)\cup(a, a+\epsilon)$

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and let $L$ be a set containing all of the limit points of $A$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary limit point of $L$, we want to show that $x\in L$ or in other-words that $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

Given an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, we know by definition of a limit point that $(V_\epsilon(x)\setminus\{x\})\cap L\neq \emptyset$ so there is at least a $l\in V_\epsilon(x)\cap L$ where $l\neq x$. Now $l\in L$ so $l$ is a limit point of $A$. We can now pick $\epsilon'>0$ small enough that $V_{\epsilon'}(l)\subseteq V_\epsilon(x)$ and $x\notin V_{\epsilon'}(l)$, then again since $l$ is a limit point of $A$, there is a $a\in V_{\epsilon'}(l)\cap A$ where $a\neq l$.

Now $a\in V_{\epsilon'}(l)\subseteq V_\epsilon(x)$ so $a\in V_\epsilon(x)$ but $x\notin V_{\epsilon'}(l)$ so $a\neq x$. Thus in conclusion for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a $a\in A$ such that $a\in V_\epsilon(x)\cap A$ and $a\neq x$ so $x$ is a limit point of $A$. $\blacksquare$.

What confused me about the previous answers was the lack of motivation for $a\neq x$, so I wanted to add this one for clarity if others found that not trivial like me.

Comment: Explicitly if $0 < \epsilon’ < \min (|x-l|,|x + \epsilon - l|, |x - \epsilon - l|) $ then it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative proof, using a proof by contradiction:

Let $x$ be any limit point of $E'$.

Assume $x \notin E'$. By the definition of limit points, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon) \cap E$ contains at most one point, $x$, in $E$. But, since $x$ is an limit point of $E'$, then there exists $y \in E'$ such that $|x - y| < \epsilon_1$. Similarly, $y$ is an limit point of $E$, so for all $\epsilon_2$, there exists $z \in E$ such that $|y - z| < \epsilon_2$. If we take the interval $|x - z|$, then:
\begin{align*}
 |x - z| &= |x + (y - y) - z| \\
    &= |(x - y) + (y - z)| \\
    &\leq |x - y| + |y - z| \tag{by triangle inequality} \\
    &< \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2
\end{align*}
We can choose $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 < \epsilon / 2,$ which means $|x - z| < \epsilon$, and every interval around $x$ contains at least two points in $E$, so $x$ is a limit point of $E$ and $x \in E'$, which contradicts our initial assumption. Therefore, every limit point of $E'$ is in $E'$.