# If we have two-point indiscrete space $X=\{a,b\}$ & let $A=\{a\}$,then what is the derived set of $A?$

Tags: general-topology, limits, alternative-proof

If we have two-point indiscrete space $X=\{a,b\}$ & let $A=\{a\}$,then what is the derived set of $A?$

**Source:** This question was discussed in my topology class.Proffessor hinted us that its derived set is $A'=\{b\}$,Which is not closed!!

**Queries:**

1.How does closed sets in 
$T_0$ space look like?

2.What is the derived set of $A$(proof?)?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $a$ is not a limit point of $S$ here.

Comment: @WilliamElliot:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490968/non-t1-space-is-the-set-of-limit-points-closed/490976#comment6736864_490976 look at the answer by Stefan Hamcke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closed sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$, the complements of the open sets.

$a \notin A'$ because a neighbourhood of $a$ is $X$ and $X \cap A  =\{a\}$ does not contain a point of $A$ different from $a$!

$b \in A'$ because again the **only** neighbourhood of $b$ is $X$ and $X \cap A= \{a\}$ contains a point of $A$ different from $b$ (namely $a$).

So $A'=\{b\}$. Which indeed is not closed.

In general, if $A=\{a\}$ in **any** space $a$ is not a limit point of $A$, because there is no other point than $a$ in $A$ (the definition of $x \in A'$ says that every open set that contains $x$ must contain a point of $A$ different from $x$, and this cannot happen for $x=a$).

Closed sets in any space (also a $T_0$ space) are just the complements of the open sets.