# Prop: Let $E'$ be the set of all limit points of $E$. Then, $E'$ is closed.

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

**Prop:** Let $E'$ be the set of all limit points of $E$. Then, $E'$ is closed.

**Pf:** A set is closed iff its complement is open. So, we wish to show that $(E')^c$ is open. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $E' \subseteq X$. There exists a  point $x\in X $ such that $B_{r_{1}}(x)\bigcap E' \neq \emptyset$ and $B_{r_{1}}(x)\bigcap (E')^c \neq \emptyset$. Since $E'$ contains all of the limit points,  there exists a neighborhood of $y \in (E')^c$ such that $B_{r_{2}}(y) \bigcap E' = \emptyset$, implying $(E')^c$ is open. Therefore, $E'$ is closed $\square$.

Does it look right?

Comment: Judging by the notation you use, you seem to be making a number of mistakes: for one, if $E^{c}$ denotes the complementary of $E$, what need is there to consider the difference $E^{c} \setminus E$? At any rate, the result you seek to prove is valid in any $T_1$ topological space: the derivative of any subset will be a closed subset.

Comment: $E^c \setminus E = E^c$

Comment: If you are interested in a proof then have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15766/75923). Also have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/490968/75923).

Answer (score 1):

There is a very general statement that can be made (in my notation, over-dots denote derivatives of subsets):

> **Proposition**. Let $(X, \mathscr{T})$ be a $T_1$-space. Then for any $M \subseteq X$ one has the relation $\ddot{M} \subseteq \dot{M}$.

*Proof:* Consider $x \in \ddot{M}$ and let $U \in \mathscr{T}$ be an arbitrary open neighbourhood of $x$ (so that $x \in U$); by definition, we must have that the following intersection is nonempty

$$(U \setminus \{x\}) \cap \dot{M} \neq \varnothing$$

so then there exists $y \in (U \setminus \{x\}) \cap \dot{M}$; we have thus that $y$ is an accumulation point for $M$. As our space is $T_1$, the singleton $\{x\}$ is closed and therefore the set-theoretic difference $V=U \setminus \{x\}$ is open (as the difference between an open subset and a closed one); hence, $V$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ and again by definition of accumulation points we must have that

$$(V \setminus \{y\}) \cap M \neq \varnothing$$

which entails

$$(U \setminus \{x\}) \cap M \neq \varnothing$$

From the arbitrariness of $U$ we conclude that $x$ is an accumulation point for $M$ as well, and thus that $\ddot{M} \subseteq \dot{M}$. $\Box$

From this one immediately obtains the following:

> **Corollary**: in a $T_1$ space any derivative is a closed subset.

*Proof:* keeping the notations from the previous paragraph, let us recall that $\overline{T}=T \cup \dot{T}$ for any subset $T \subseteq X$. In particular, we will have $\overline{\dot{M}}=\dot{M} \cup \ddot{M}=\dot{M}$, by virtue of the proposition above, which tells us that the derivative of $M$ is indeed closed. $\Box$

Metric spaces are Hausdorff spaces, which is a stronger separation property than $T_1$ so the above applies to them in particular.

As an additional remark, it can be shown that

> **Proposition**: Let $(X, \mathscr{T})$ be an *arbitrary* topological space and $F \subseteq X$ a *closed* subset. Then the derivative $\dot{F}$ is also closed (in other words, **derivatives of closed subsets remain closed, without any hypothesis on the ambient space**).