# Proving the set of all limit points of a set is closed - alternative proof.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I'm working through Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, and came across the following problem.

> Let $E'$ be the set of all limit points of a set $E$. Prove $E'$ is closed.

*My proof:* 
Consider $F = E \setminus E'$ and $y \in F$. Then since $y$ is not a limit point of $E$, $\exists \ \delta > 0$ such that $B_{\delta}(y) \cap E' = \emptyset$. But then $F$ is open, so $E'$ is closed. $\square$

---

Naturally I wanted to convince myself this was correct, and upon doing some looking around online ([*see question asked here on MSE*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/proving-that-the-set-of-limit-points-of-a-set-is-closed), *or* [*UCSD homework solutions paper*](http://math.ucsd.edu/~lni/math140/HW2_solutions.pdf)) it seems to me like the "normal" way to prove this is to show that every limit point of $E'$ is in fact a point of $E'$.

This has made me question whether there is a flaw in my argument, or whether it looks correct and is reasonable enough to just show that the complement is open?

Comment: It's correct, and better than the standard argument.

Comment: @Eric Hansen: I don't understand your proof. The set $E'$ is not necessary a subset of $E$. Do you mean $F = E \setminus (E \cap E')$ or $F = X \setminus E'$ where $X$ is the space in which we work?

Comment: @levap Ahh no you're not misunderstanding you're completely right, for some reason I just assumed $E$ already contained all of its limit points. This is just incorrect then I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **levap** pointed out in the comments, you’ve implicitly assumed that $E'\subseteq E$, which need not be true. However, it is still *half* of a correct argument. Since $\operatorname{cl}E=E\cup E'$, we know that

$$\begin{align*}
(E\setminus E')\cup(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E)&=(E\setminus E')\cup\big(X\setminus(E\cup E')\big)\\
&=(E\setminus E')\cup\big((X\setminus E)\cap(X\setminus E')\big)\\
&=(E\setminus E')\cup\big((X\setminus E)\setminus E'\big)\\
&=X\setminus E'\;.
\end{align*}$$

You’ve shown that if $x\in E\setminus E'$, then $x$ has an open nbhd disjoint from $E'$. And $X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E$ is open and disjoint from $E'$, so every point of $X\setminus\operatorname{cl}E$ certainly has an open nbhd disjoint from $E'$. Thus, every point of $X\setminus E'$ has an open nbhd disjoint from $E'$, and $E'$ is therefore closed.

Comment: Thanks Brian, this is a nicer version of what my fixed proof ended up looking like as well!

Comment: @Eric: You’re welcome; I’m glad that you were able to fix it up!