# Basic question on closure of the set of limit points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We have the [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/proving-that-the-set-of-limit-points-of-a-set-is-closed):

> Let $E′$ be the set of all limit points of a set $E$. Prove that $E′$ is closed.

I understand the proof by Roberto Cardona given in the link, what I still don't grasp is essentially the closure of $E'$. In other words, why I have to suppose that $x_0\in E'$ *is a limit point of $E'$*? If I assume this, then by definition (*) $E'$ is closed and the only thing that I prove is that $x_0$ is also a limit of $E$ (i.e. that I don't create somehow limit points that are not limit points of $E$).

> (*) A set $E'\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed if it contains all its limit points.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion.  The proof does _not_ assume that $x_0\in E'$, and you seem to acknowledge this when you say you still need to prove that $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$.

Comment: I see now where I misunderstood the argument. Thanks!

Comment: The guy says "Thus $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$ and by definition is contained in $E'$, so I understood that $x_0\in E'$ from the beginning.  I think is better to write "Thus $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$ and therefore $x_0\in E'$". I still get lost in the semantics...

Answer (score 1):

The proof starts by : let $x_0$ be a limit point of $E'$. Then (insert argument), $x_0 \in E'$. So we have shown that any limit point of $E'$ is already in $E'$ (or $E'' \subseteq E'$) so the criterion $(\ast)$ allows one to conclude that $E'$ is closed. The criterion $(\ast)$ is better formulated as

> A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed if it contains all its limit points.

Or

> A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed if $A' \subseteq A$

which we apply to $A  =E'$.