# Closedness of the set of limit points of a set $E$ is closed seems contradictory

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set $E = \left\{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \cdots\right\} \cup \left\{1\frac{1}{2},1\frac{1}{3}, \cdots\right\}$. Observe that when we consider the space to be $\mathbb{R}$, $0$ and $1$ are the only limit points of the set $E$ but $\{0,1\}$ is not closed.

For ref., A set is *closed* in space $\mathcal{X}$ if it contains all its limit points.

Can anyone tell me with an example what [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15766/proving-that-the-set-of-limit-points-of-a-set-is-closed) post is about?

Comment: Alright, so I thought that a limit point is considering by taking "only" the "deleted" neighbourhoods of the concerned point (that which we call the limit point) and by this definition, any finite set doesn't seem to be closed.

Comment: Using your definition, $\{0,1\}$ has no limit points, so it contains all of its zero limits points, hence it is closed.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

According to your definition of closed set, a set $A$ is *not* closed if there exists a limit point $x$ of $A$ such that $x\notin A$.

Now, what are the limit points of $\{0,1\}$? Can you find one that does not belong to $\{0,1\}$?

---

Suppose $x$ is a limit point of $A$ in the metric space $(X,d)$. Then there exists $x_0\in A$ such that $x\ne x_0$ and $d(x,x_0)<1$.

Suppose you have found $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n\in A$, $x_k\ne x$, pairwise distinct. Now, by assumption, there exists $x_{n+1}\in A$, $x_{n+1}\ne x$ with $d(x_{n+1},x)<d(x_n,x)/2$. In particular, the points $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1}$ belong to $A$ and are pairwise distinct.

The recursion doesn't end, so you have a sequence $(x_n)$ of pairwise distinct points of $A$. Hence $A$ is infinite.